# how to send angular class instance to web api httpget action C#

Tags: c#, angular, webapi

I've a class like this in angular

```
export class UserSearch {
     firstName: string;
     lastName: string;
     city: string;
     stateCode: string;
}
```

I wanted to send an instance of UserSearch with data to web api from angular.
I've used below 2 different ways but still no luck.  I can always see null at web api.
Code in angular service:

```
getSearchResults() {
var request: UserSearch = {} as any;
request.firstName='fName';
request.lastName='lName';
request.city='city1';
request.stateCode='sCode';
            
var params = new HttpParams().append('searchRequest', JSON.stringify(request));
return this.http.get('https://localhost:44348/api/userSearchResults/search', params);
}
```

Api is receiving null if i use the above procedure.
So, I've tried like following:

```
getSearchResults() {
var request: UserSearch = {} as any;
request.firstName='fName';
request.lastName='lName';
request.city='city1';
request.stateCode='sCode';
            
 return this.http.get(`https://localhost:44348/api/userSearchResults/search?searchRequest=${request}`);
                    }
```

But still no luck, web api action method still receiving null.

Here is my web api action method:

```
[HttpGet, Route("search")]
public IActionResult Search(UserSearch searchRequest) {
return Ok(_service.GetSearchResults(searchRequest));
}
```

UserSearch class in C# web api looks like following:

```
public class UserSearch {
public string firstName {get; set;}
public string lastName {get; set;}
public string city {get; set;}
public string stateCode {get; set;}
}
```

What is the best way to send class instance with data to web api controller from angular?
Can someone please go through the code and let me where am I doing wrong?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: you need to set headers and options as below :    var headers = new HttpHeaders();
      headers.append('Content-Type', undefined);
      const httpOptions = {
        headers: headers, reportProgress: true
      };

Comment: Hi Guys, I personally feel that modelbinder concept is not a good idea as we need to have an entry in startup.cs file for each and every viewmodel that we are going to create in our application.  Which is not a good idea.  Anyway I found the easy solution for this:
The only chage that I made at angular service which you can see in my next comment as no space in this comment box to leave my code snippet.

Comment: Here is my solution:  
getSearchResults(request: UserSearch) {
        var params = new HttpParams().set('firstName', request.firstName).set('lastName',request.lastName)
                    .set('city',request.city).set('stateCode',request.stateCode);
        return this.http.get('https://localhost:44348/api/userSearchResults/search', params);
    }
with this I can see values at web api action nmethod.

Answer (score 0):

try to use [FromUri], like this:

```
public IActionResult Search([FromUri] UserSearch searchRequest)
```